# Flutter - How will you check from which screen you have clicked bottom navigation tab

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bottomnavigation

I am trying to find how can I know from which screen user has clicked the bottom nav screen. Basically I have to send event from which screen user clicked on botton nav. I have 4 bottom nav.

Comment: share the code please.

Comment: You can use @Shripad Jadhav answer then save the page index with shared preference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to check a previously selected item in the bottom bar what you can do you can make use of

`onTap: (index) => changeTab(index)`

It gives an index of the item user taps, Save index to some variable, and next time when use tap on the item you can consider previously saved value as an item from which the user is tapping.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the last selected index in bottom navigation bar :

```
 static int currentTab = 0;
 static int lastIndex = 0;
```

When you implement the onPressed or onTap method on bottom bar:

```
 onTap: (){
  setState(() {
      currentTab = index;
      lastIndex = currentTab;    // It keeps the last selected index.
    }
  });
}
```

And then u can call

```
    currentTab = lastIndex.
```